# Conditional view modifier sometimes doesn't want to update

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

As I am working on a study app, I'm tring to build a set of cards, that a user can swipe each individual card, in this case a view, in a foreach loop and when flipped through all of them, it resets the cards to normal stack. The program works but sometimes the stack of cards doesn't reset. Each individual card updates a variable in a viewModel which my conditional view modifier looks at, to reset the stack of cards using offset and when condition is satisfied, the card view updates, while using ".onChange" to look for the change in the viewModel to then update the variable back to original state.

I've printed each variable at each step of the way and every variable updates and I can only assume that the way I'm updating my view, using conditional view modifier, may not be the correct way to go about. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

**Here is my code:
The view that houses the card views with the conditional view modifier**

```
extension View {

    @ViewBuilder func `resetCards`<Content: View>(_ condition: Bool, transform: (Self) -> Content) -> some View {
        if condition == true {
            transform(self).offset(x: 0, y: 0)
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}

struct StudyListView: View {

    @ObservedObject var currentStudySet: HomeViewModel
    @ObservedObject var studyCards: StudyListViewModel = StudyListViewModel()
    
    @State var studyItem: StudyModel
    @State var index: Int

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(currentStudySet.allSets[index].studyItem.reversed()) { item in
            StudyCardItemView(currentCard: studyCards, card: item, count: currentStudySet.allSets[index].studyItem.count)
                .resetCards(studyCards.isDone) { view in
                    view
                }
                .onChange(of: studyCards.isDone, perform: { _ in
                    studyCards.isDone = false
                })
            }
     }
}
```

**StudyCardItemView**

```
struct StudyCardItemView: View {

    @StateObject var currentCard: StudyListViewModel
    @State var card: StudyItemModel
    @State var count: Int
    
    @State var offset = CGSize.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            VStack{
                ZStack(alignment: .center){
                    Text("\(card.itemTitle)")
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 350, height: 200)
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .shadow(radius: 5)
        .padding(5)
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(Double(offset.width / 5)))
        .offset(x: offset.width * 5, y: 0)
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { gesture in
                    offset = gesture.translation
                }
                .onEnded{ _ in
                    if abs(offset.width) > 100 {
                        currentCard.cardsSortedThrough += 1
                        if (currentCard.cardsSortedThrough == count) {
                            currentCard.isDone = true
                            currentCard.cardsSortedThrough = 0
                        }
                    } else {
                        offset = .zero
                    }
                }
        )
    }
}
```

**HomeViewModel**

```
class HomeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var studySet: StudyModel = StudyModel()
    @Published var allSets: [StudyModel] = [StudyModel()]
}
```

I initialize allSets with one StudyModel() to see it in the preview

**StudyListViewModel**

```
class StudyListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var cardsSortedThrough: Int = 0
    @Published var isDone: Bool = false
}
```

**StudyModel**

```
import SwiftUI

struct StudyModel: Hashable{
    var title: String = ""
    var days = ["One day", "Two days", "Three days", "Four days", "Five days", "Six days", "Seven days"]
    var studyGoals = "One day"
    
    var studyItem: [StudyItemModel] = []
}
```

Lastly, **StudyItemModel**

```
struct StudyItemModel: Hashable, Identifiable{
    let id = UUID()
    var itemTitle: String = ""
    var itemDescription: String = ""
}
```

Once again, any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: I didn't really get too much into details, but shouldn't `studyCards.isDone` in the `.resetCards(studyCards.isDone)` be bound, i.e. `.resetCards($studyCards.isDone)` - again this is just based on quick scan of the code.

Comment: @akjndklskver no because the .resetCards doesn't have code to change studyCards.isDone , at least I don't think.

Comment: its best to just have one object that stores the model structs and is responsible for persisting them and use binding to pass write access down

Comment: @malhal I see what you mean by that, and I was thinking if I tried putting the offset variable from **StudyCardItemView** in **StudyItemModel**, the view can individuality change its offsets for each view since it's in an array, and I can set the offset to `.zero`, from `onchange` in **StudyListView** but when I try setting CGSize for offset variable in **StudyItemModel**, I get _Type StudyItemModel does not conform to protocol Hashable_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a fix and I put .onChange at the end for **StudyCardItemView**. Basically, the onChange helps the view scan for a change in **currentCard.isDone** variable every time it was called in the foreach loop and updates offset individuality. This made my conditional view modifier obsolete and just use the onChange to check for the condition.

I still used onChange outside the view with the foreach loop, just to set **currentCard.isDone** variable false because the variable will be set after all array elements are iterator through.

The updated code:
**StudyCardItemView**

```
struct StudyCardItemView: View {

    @StateObject var currentCard: StudyListViewModel
    @State var card: StudyItemModel
    @State var count: Int
    
    @State var offset = CGSize.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            VStack{
                ZStack(alignment: .center){
                    Text("\(card.itemTitle)")
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 350, height: 200)
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .shadow(radius: 5)
        .padding(5)
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(Double(offset.width / 5)))
        .offset(x: offset.width * 5, y: 0)
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { gesture in
                    offset = gesture.translation
                }
                .onEnded{ _ in
                    if abs(offset.width) > 100 {
                        currentCard.cardsSortedThrough += 1
                        if (currentCard.cardsSortedThrough == count) {
                            currentCard.isDone = true
                            currentCard.cardsSortedThrough = 0
                        }
                    } else {
                        offset = .zero
                    }
                }
        )
        .onChange(of: currentCard.isDone, perform: {_ in 
           offset = .zero
        })
    }
}
```

**StudyListView**

```
struct StudyListView: View {

    @ObservedObject var currentStudySet: HomeViewModel
    @ObservedObject var studyCards: StudyListViewModel = StudyListViewModel()
    
    @State var studyItem: StudyModel
    @State var index: Int

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(currentStudySet.allSets[index].studyItem.reversed()) { item in
            StudyCardItemView(currentCard: studyCards, card: item, count: 
            currentStudySet.allSets[index].studyItem.count)
                .onChange(of: studyCards.isDone, perform: { _ in
                    studyCards.isDone = false
                })
            }
     }
}
```

Hope this helps anyone in the future!